# JQuery Tabs and Event Bubbling

Tags: jquery-tabs, event-bubbling

The prohlem is that the JQuery Tabs downloaded from [JQuery Theme Roller](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/) is not bubbling any events beyond that.

For example, I have a click event listener for "body" tag. But clicking on any tab of theme roller does not fire the body-tag-click-event-handler.

I think the JQuery Tabs code is stoping event propagation. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: I could probably help you fix it, but not without seeing your code. Consider editing your question to include that information. In general, it's a good practice to show what you've done so far when asking questions on StackOverflow. Good luck!